# Rewriting VS 2013 SPA Template to use Angular/HotTowel

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, access-token

I am trying to integrate Hot Towel-Angular with the SPA Template. The one issue that I'm having is retrieving the access_token from a redirect to the AuthorizeEndPointPath. In Fiddler, I can see the access_token being returned in the Location header of the response for the 302 status redirect but there doesn't appear to be a way to capture that in Angular. All that I can get from the call is the 200 status from the redirected page.

Looking at the OOB SPA template provided that uses knockout, I haven't figured out how the windows.location.hash property is used to extract the access_token. Modifying the same code in angular has led to a complete dead end. Have also tried using a response interceptor with no luck as others have tried the same approach.

Others here have posted about this same approach and look to have come to the same conclusion. If the MSDN documentation wasn't complete rubbish, maybe someone could figure it out. Really wish MSDN documentation didn't totally suck. MS really should hire better technical writers.

Started to think the only workaround is to store username and password in session storage and if login is successful, use the /token endpoint to get the token as that works fine. Seems like a pointless hack though. Anyone have any other ideas?

[Web Api OAuth with Angular front end - Cannot handle 302 redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21501305/web-api-oauth-with-angular-front-end-cannot-handle-302-redirect)